# Weirdly behaviour when testing TypeORM repository findAndCount

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, integration-testing, typeorm, sinon

I'm trying to test pagination on a service that's mean to return many objects of my database based on a given Entity of TypeORM.

My idea was to generate random entities and examples of it using this:

```js
    const entities = [
        {
            entity: Predio,
            creator: onePredio
        },
        {
            entity: UsoDeSuelo,
            creator: oneUsoDeSuelo
        },
        {
            entity: Propuesta,
            creator: onePropuesta
        },
        {
            entity: Estudio,
            creator: oneEstudio
        },
        {
            entity: Solicitud,
            creator: oneSolicitud
        },
        {
            entity: Promotor,
            creator: onePromotor
        }
    ];
    const selectedEntity = entities[Math.floor(Math.random() * entities.length)];
    const entity = selectedEntity.entity;
    const creator = selectedEntity.creator;

    const entityRepository = appDataSource.getRepository(entity);

    const NUM_ELEMENTS_TO_CREATE = 10;

    const elements = fakeMultiple<any>({ times: NUM_ELEMENTS_TO_CREATE, creator: creator });
```

Here i'm generating one entity and its properties in order to fake them. An example of a function called "oneSomething" looks like the following:

```js
const onePropuesta = (id: string = v4()): Propuesta => {

    return {
        id,
        giro: faker.lorem.words(3),
        tipoPropuesta: faker.lorem.words(3),
        predioAPropuesta: [],
    }
};

const fakeMultiple = <T>(options: { times?: number, creator: () => T }): T[] => {
    const { times = 5, creator } = options;
    const arr: T[] = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        arr.push(creator());
    }
    return arr;
};
```

This seems kind of fine for me, because it makes sense to generate a dynamic type of test for a service that's going to return information about an entity based on the entity passed by.

My test is the following:

```js
    it.only('Should return an array of objects of a given entity paginated', (done) => {
        const findFake = sinon.fake.resolves([elements, elements.length]);

        sinon.replace(entityRepository, 'findAndCount', findFake);

        const options = {
            skip: 1,
            take: 3
        }

        findMany(entity, options)
            .then(data => {
                expect(findFake.calledOnceWithExactly(options)).to.be.true;
                done();
            })
            .catch(done);

    });
```

And my service is this one:

```js
const findMany = async <T extends ObjectLiteral>(entity: EntityTarget<T>, options: FindManyOptions) => {
    const entityRepository = appDataSource.getRepository(entity);

    const [entities, count] = await entityRepository.findAndCount(options);

    console.log(entities);
    return {
        data: entities,
        total: count
    };
};
```

When running this test, my service is ignoring the "options" param, and returning the whole 10 objects that I generate to fake data, it should only return 3 elements.

The weird thing here is that, when I run my test like this:

```js
        findMany(**'Entity'**, options)
            .then(data => {
                expect(findFake.calledOnceWithExactly(options)).to.be.true;
                done();
            })
            .catch(done);
```

It **does** return 3 items of given Entity, for example, "Estudio" or "Predio".
Can someone help me on what i'm doing wrong here? Or even if my approach is correct for my scenario.